# Is the map $t \mapsto (1-t)x + ty$ where $x,y$ in a Banach space a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

Suppose we have two distinct fixed points $x, y \in X$ where $X$ is a Banach space. If we define $\gamma: [0,1] \to X$ by $t \mapsto (1-t)x + ty$, I think the map $\gamma: [0,1] \mapsto \gamma([0,1])$ when restricted on the image is a homeomorphism.

The way I would to prove is to note the map is bijective and open since $t \mapsto t(x-y)$ is open by open mapping theorem and translation is a homeomorphism. Is this argument correct? Is there some more direct way to see this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works (assuming you are applying the open mapping theorem to the span of $x-y$) but the open mapping theorem is massive overkill.  You can just observe that $\gamma$ is a closed map since $[0,1]$ is compact and $X$ is Hausdorff (if $A\subseteq[0,1]$ is closed then it is compact so $\gamma(A)$ is compact so $\gamma(A)$ is closed).

Or, even more simply, observe that the norm on the span of $x-y$ is just $\|t(x-y)\|=|t|\|x-y\|$.  So $\gamma$ just multiplies distances by $\|x-y\|$.  It follows that the inverse of $\gamma$ just multiplies all distances by $\frac{1}{\|x-y\|}$ and so is continuous.

Comment: Thanks, Eric, for always providing insights for me.

Comment: Hi Eric. I thought open mapping argument again today. I was initially thinking applying the open mapping theorem between the subspace $[0,1]$ and the closed line segement $[x,y] = \{(1-t)x+ty: t \in [0,1]\}$. In your answer, if we apply to the span and then we need to take a restriction, but the restriction is not necessarily open, right? What's the argument in you mind? Thanks.

Comment: What I had in mind is that the map from $\mathbb{R}$ to the span of $y-x$ sending $t$ to $t(y-x)$ is open and therefore a homeomorphism.  So, its restriction to $[0,1]$ is a homeomorphism to its image.

Comment: I see. Thanks .